# Find total duration of a specific event per item

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle11g

The table structure looks like follows:

```
+-------------------------+---------------+--------------------------------------+---------+
|        timestamp        |  event_type   |               user_id                |  label  |
+-------------------------+---------------+--------------------------------------+---------+
| 2016-06-11 16:22:06.384 | SearchResults | 9df64989-9b1a-4bee-a69a-381092573185 | 4       |
| 2016-06-11 16:22:06.402 | SeeMore       | 9df64989-9b1a-4bee-a69a-381092573185 | KS31494 |
| 2016-06-11 16:22:06.708 | ServerSearch  | 152ef390-8e62-498a-b861-6586febe6f83 | 19969   |
| 2016-06-11 16:22:06.83  | ServerSearch  | 9a3706ca-da63-451b-b54c-35adbb52ad96 | 184     |
| 2016-06-11 16:22:06.912 | ServerSearch  | ab0aceba-f4f1-45df-9799-61b307290764 | 6332    |
| 2016-06-11 16:22:07.01  | DebtReminder  | 60dc13b1-ade5-43aa-82e9-37c544dc6c5d | red     |
+-------------------------+---------------+--------------------------------------+---------+
```

The `label` value in this table only makes sense in case of the *SeeMore* event and represents a car id, otherwise it is meaningless for the given scenario.

We are interested in the total duration of all *SeeMore* events for each car id - meaningful `label`.

Duration of a separate *SeeMore* evebt is specified as time difference for a specific `user_id` between the *SeeMore* `event_type` and any subsequent event.

How do i find a total duration of all *SeeMore* events for all car ids( meaningful `label`s) ?

Comment: I can see a single row for `SeeMore`. So there should be no difference, I guess.

Comment: That is an example :) Full dataset is > 200 MI. There are plenty of SeeMore events :)

Comment: And what about car? Nothing specified for that. How do you expect others to understand this? If possible, show more data or sample table. Be more specific about sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select user_id,timestamp,next_timestamp-timestamp as time_diff
from
(
select 
timestamp,
user_id, 
case when event_type='SeeMore' then 1 else 0 end as SM,
lead(timestamp) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as next_timestamp
from event_table
)
where SM=1
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what i needed! Having been using MySql for the last 6 month and thus completely forgot how analytical functions work :)